how to extract nested object from HTTPClient
In my Jquery,
getcustomHeaders function returns
{
    "customHeaders": {
        "customId": "26",
        "screenData": "width=1920&height=1080&scaling-factor=1&colour-depth=24",
        "screenSize": "width=1920&height=1080",
    }
}

Another function does,
$.ajax({
          url: 'someName/Submit?productId=' + productId,
          type: 'post',
          headers: getcustomHeaders()
        })
        .success(function(d) {
          if (d && d.responseJSON && d.responseJSON.Message) { alert(d.responseJSON.Message); }
        })
        .error(function(d) {
          if (d && d.responseJSON && d.responseJSON.Message) {
            alert(d.responseJSON.Message);
          } else {
            alert(display_some_error_message);
          }
        });

In .Net,
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
request.Headers["customHeaders"];

-- Returns the current object, but cannot access the values from the object.
I tried,
request.Headers["customHeaders"]["customId"] -- NameValueCollection doesn't contain a definition for 'customHeaders'
request.Headers["customHeaders"].GetValues("customId").FirstOrDefault() -- 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetValues'

Can any one point out me how to get the value of 'customId' please?

Why are you posting JSON in the headers instead of the body? There's no call to HttpClient in the code either. Headers contain strings, not objects. JSON is just text until something parses it into an object or array

Since you are saying

In .Net,
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
request.Headers["customHeaders"];
-- Returns the current object, but cannot access the values from the object.

I think that you need to deserialize the customHeaders json into an equivalent custom object in .Net and then access the property.
public class CustomHeaders
{
    public string CustomId {get;set;}
    public string ScreenData {get;set;}
    public string ScreenSize {get;set;}
}

And then in your
var customHeadersObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CustomHeaders>(HttpContext.Request.Headers["CustomHeaders"])

Once you do this, you will be able to access the properties like so:
customHeadersObj.CustomId

Note: Please make sure to add Jsonproperty Attribute to the properties if you are not using the exact names with casing like in your example "customId" in Ajax call vs "CustomId" in .Net
